# Bind list of objects to POST request and check object type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an `Employee` class which looks like the following:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Availability> Availabilities;
    public ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

Along with two classes that inherit from `Employee`, called `Physiotherapist`:

```cs
public class Physiotherapist : Employee
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string BigNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And `Assistant`:

```cs
public class Assistant : Employee
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a page where a new `Patient` can be created according to the `CreatePatientModel`:

```cs
public class CreatePatientModel : IValidatableObject
{
    ...
    public IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; } // My possible solution

    public int SelectedIntakeEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int IntakeSupervisorId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // My possible solution
        var selectedEmployeeObject = Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == SelectedIntakeEmployeeId);

        // I would like to do something like this; check the type of the dropdown selection.
        if (selectedIntakeEmployee is Assistant) {
            // Check if an intake supervisor has been selected, if not return ValidationResult error.
        }

    }
}
```

Once this create page gets loaded from the server side the dropdown options are retrieved (`Id` and `FirstName`) and stored in the view bag, to be used in the UI:

```cs
// List of employees
var employees = _employeeRepository.GetAllEmployees()
    .Prepend(new Core.Domain.Employee { Id = -1, FirstName = "Select an employee" });

ViewBag.Employees = new SelectList(employees, "Id", "FirstName");

// List of physiotherapists 
var physiotherapists = _employeeRepository.GetAllEmployees().Where(e => e is Physiotherapist)
    .Prepend(new Core.Domain.Employee { Id = -1, FirstName = "Select a physiotherapist" });

ViewBag.Physiotherapists = new SelectList(physiotherapists, "Id", "FirstName");
```

Finally, the options are shown on the `Create.cshtml` page like so:

```html
<div class="large-container">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="Create" method="post">
        ...
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="SelectedIntakeEmployeeId" class="control-label">Intake employee</label>
            <select id="employee-selector" class="form-control" asp-for="SelectedIntakeEmployeeId" asp-items="@ViewBag.Employees"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="IntakeSupervisorId" class="control-label">Intake supervisor</label>
            <select class="form-control" asp-for="IntakeSupervisorId" asp-items="@ViewBag.Physiotherapists"></select>
        </div>
        ...
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now onto the actual question... ;)
Once the submit button is clicked, the `Validate()` method of the `CreatePatientModel` is executed. Here, I would like to be able to check the selected type of the dropdown. I other words, I would like to check whether the selected option is of type `Physiotherpist` or `Assistant`, to then notify the user that selecting a supervisor (a fysiotherpist) is required when the selected intake employee is an assistant.

My initial thought was to include a list of all employees in the `CreatePatientModel`, by setting this property when the page is being loaded from the server, and then lookup the selected intake employee and check the type (as shown in the `CreatePatientModel` code snippet above). However, I found this to be quite difficult as it isn't easy (as far as I know) to pass the whole list of employees along with the POST request when the form is submitted.

I tried something like this inside the `Create.cshtml` form:

```html
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Employees.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Employees[i].Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Employees[i].FirstName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Employees[i].LastName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Employees[i].Email)
    </div>
}
```

But this does not pass the object type (Physiotherapist or Assistant) with the request.

So I was wondering, is there a better way to check the selected type of employee inside the `Validate()` method of the `CreatePatientModel`? Maybe in a different way?

Comment: Why not just have an `EmployeeType` property on the `Employee`? Then you just check that value. You can set that value in the descendant classes too, `class Physiotherapist : Employee { public string EmployeeType { get => "Physiotherapist"; } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your question, I think you want to pass all the value of `employee` from view to `Employees` property in `CreatePatientModel`.

Actually you don't need to do that, I noticed that you have a `GetAllEmployees()` method in `EmployeeRepository`, So you just need to inject `EmployeeRepository` into `CreatePatientModel` and use `GetAllEmployees()` method to get all Employees.

```
public class CreatePatientModel : IValidatableObject
{
    //...
    //.....inject EmployeeRepository into this class.....

    public int SelectedIntakeEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int IntakeSupervisorId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
       
        var selectedEmployeeObject = _employeeRepository.GetAllEmployees().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == SelectedIntakeEmployeeId);
           
        //............

    }
}
```